# Покажите как с помощью NDP найти DNS сервер

Tags: c, сеть, протоколы

Я прочитал в описании NDP протокола: "Рекурсивный DNS-сервер (RDNSS) и список поиска DNS (DNSSL) назначается через параметры отклика маршрутизатора (RA).[3] Это новая функция, и поддерживается не всем программным обеспечением.". Это Википедия. Также это есть ещё на нескольких сайтах. Но в RFC стандарте про это не написано. И я не смог найти подробной информации. Помогите пожалуйста.